# General expression for total length

Tags: geometry

**i want to derive an expression to calculate the total length of the green lines in the following figure.**

1. Firstly we have a L-shape frame of green lines where, L1, W1, L2, W2
   are lengths of the sides to which they are placed.
2. Horizontal green lines are places inside the frame starting from the bottom, each "D" distance apart.
3. Vertical green lines are placed inside the frame starting from the left, each "D" distance apart.
4. Arrow shows the direction how the lines are placed.
5. The last vertical/horizontal green line is "D or less" distance from the green line that forms the L-shape frame.

[image: figure]

[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt4yq.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, show your efforts so far.

Comment: I came up with 8 conditions where the top, two sides of L corner and right sides of the figure may either have perfect "D" spacing or "less than D".

Comment: Hint: Decompose the "L" by stretching "L2" and "W2" sides up to left and bottom L sides. Then find how many of those perfect/less lines you have in each of the three resulting rectangles.

Comment: @Ni2 not sixteen?

Comment: Yea 16 i said 8 by mistake. @Anton